# How to create AND NAME a temp file in PHP that is then sent on?

Tags: php, temporary-files

I need to create a temp file in PHP, put some JSON info in it, NAME IT, and then send it off into an API - which is why it must be named.

so, i've come across the `[tmpfile][1]` and the `[tempnam][2]` function - it doesn't seem like either one of them lets me name the files while they're open...

So, how do I do this?

Comment: Do you have something against just creating a file then unlinking it after you send it to the api? By that I mean using basic fopen and fwrite functions

Comment: "off to an api"? as in an http api? the http stuff won't care if you're reading the data from a file or a string.

Comment: well, I don't want the file to hang around on my side - this file will have to do with the task at hand, and the intention is to send it off every time, with the same name - the destination is different every time. but have to ATTACH a file, can't just send the info. @KaiQing - are you suggesting i use fopen, name it, put info in it, send it and unlink it? that can work, if there's not a more elegant solution..